# Send exceljs workbook to Backend

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, symfony, exceljs

In my client side , i created an excel file , i worked with `exceljs`workbook.
I would like to send that excel file to my backend side (symfony ).
my code :

```
 sendExcel(fileObj : File) {
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'});
 let options = { headers: headers };
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', fileObj);
 return this.httpClient.post('api/ExcelToPdf/',formData,options).pipe(
   map(res => res ));
 }

 this.myservice.sendExcel(this.workbook).subscribe((res) => { 
 console.log(res)});
```

In my backend server i test for the existance of the file. in my case , i don't get any .
but with POSTMAN everything is alright !

[POSTMAN Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INSUt.png)

Then i visualise that the problem is in the notebook instance.

```
   this.workbook = new Workbook();
```

it is not considered as a file. 
it there a way to cast it as a file ? i worked with `exceljs`.

backend code:

```
 public function exceltopdfAction(Request $request){
    $file = $request->files->get('file');
    dump(count($_FILES));
    return new JsonResponse(count($_FILES));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the backend fn

Comment: What is the HTTP Verb .. POST or PUT?

Comment: i'm using POST . but i tried both

Comment: Hmm... Can you send the complete screenshot of how is it working with POSTMAN

Comment: image uploaded ..